# immediate deleting database despite the open connections

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a live database that has existing connections. I want to delete this database regardless of any open connections.

I use SQL Server Management Studio.

What is the bast way:

- `detach` command and then delete physical file?
- `delete` command?

I hope the question is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDbName]
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

DROP DATABASE [YourDbName]
GO
```

Raj

Comment: is GO command between SINGLE_USER and DROP DATABASE required?